# Why do we have two separate transforms for transforming a time domain signal to the frequency domain?

Tags: signal-processing, fourier, laplace-transform

I know that Laplace transform and Fourier transform are not exactly equal; they will be equal when alpha = jω.

But according to my understanding, both transforms convert a time domain signal to the frequency domain.

I am confused regarding their differences, and especially their applications. When and where do we use the Laplace transform and when and where do we use the Fourier transform?

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate because there are already three or four questions asking exactly the same thing with numerous answers. If you read those and still don't understand something, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Have you tried to do any research before asking? For example, read the Wikipedia article on Laplace transform which also compares the relationship to Fourier transform?